# Why .css is not working in Symfony form added with render controller using Twig?

Tags: css, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I am adding a form inside HTML content with render controller (Twig), but the .css styles are not being recognized for that specific content, for the rest of the content there is no problem.

The HTML is into one file called `footer.html` with this content:

```
{% apply inline_css %}
    <footer id="footer"> 
      <div class="footer-newsletter"> 
        <div class="container"> 
          <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-lg-6"> 
              <h4>Our Newsletter</h4> <p>Tamen quem nulla quae legam multos aute sint culpa legam noster magna</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-lg-6">  {{ render(controller(
                'App\\Controller\\SubscribeController::new'
            )) }}    
            </div>
            ... etc
{% endapply %}
```

And I am adding this file in a Twig template with include:

```
...

{% include 'footer.html' %}

...
```

When I test the page in the browser, it generates the form well, but the styles for the content that is created using `{{ render(controller( 'App\\Controller\\SubscribeController::new' )) }}` are not applied.

In the next snippet I put the generated HTML and the .css and styles do apply here. I would like to know why they do not apply when testing the page directly and what should I do to make them apply.

```css
#footer {
  background: #404040;
  padding: 0 0 30px 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px
}

#footer .footer-newsletter {
  padding: 50px 0;
  background: #404040
}

#footer .footer-newsletter h4 {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 600
}

#footer .footer-newsletter form {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px
}

#footer .footer-newsletter form button#subscribe_Suscribir {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  margin: 3px;
  background: #e96b56;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 50px
}

#footer .footer-newsletter form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #e6573f
}

#footer .footer-top {
  background: #3b3b3b;
  border-top: 1px solid #474747;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #474747;
  padding: 60px 0 30px 0
}

#footer .footer-top .footer-info {
  margin-bottom: 30px
}

#footer .footer-top .footer-info h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding: 2px 0 2px 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 700
}

#footer .footer-top .footer-info p {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  color: #fff
}

#footer .footer-top .social-links a {
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #545454;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 8px 0;
  margin-right: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  transition: 0.3s
}

#footer .footer-top .social-links a:hover {
  background: #e96b56;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none
}

#footer .footer-top h4 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 12px
}

#footer .footer-top .footer-links {
  margin-bottom: 30px
}

#footer .footer-top .footer-links ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

#footer .footer-top .footer-links ul i {
  padding-right: 2px;
  color: #ec7f6d;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1
}

#footer .footer-top .footer-links ul li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}

#footer .footer-top .footer-links ul li:first-child {
  padding-top: 0
}

#footer .footer-top .footer-links ul a {
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1
}

#footer .footer-top .footer-links ul a:hover {
  color: #e96b56
}

#footer .footer-top .footer-contact {
  margin-bottom: 30px
}

#footer .footer-top .footer-contact p {
  line-height: 26px
}

#footer .copyright {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px
}

#footer .credits {
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff
}

label.required:before {
  content: "*";
}

#subscribe_email {
  color: red;
  border: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  width: calc(100% - 140px)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hello PostController!</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="data:image/svg+xml,&lt;svg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 128 128%22&gt;&lt;text y=%221.2em%22 font-size=%2296%22&gt;⚫️&lt;/text&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/app.css">

  <script src="/build/runtime.js" defer=""></script>
  <script src="/build/vendors-node_modules_symfony_stimulus-bridge_dist_index_js-node_modules_bootstrap_dist_js_boo-e61552.js" defer=""></script>
  <script src="/build/app.js" defer=""></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="example-wrapper">
    <h1>Hello Hello world!! ✅</h1>

    This friendly message is coming from: Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!
  </div>


  <footer id="footer">
    <div class="footer-newsletter">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h4>Our* Newsletter</h4>
            <p>Tamen quem nulla quae legam multos aute sint culpa legam noster magna</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <form name="subscribe" method="get" action="/subscription">
              <div class="my-custom-class-for-errors">

              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col" id="id-email">
                  <div>
                    <label for="subscribe_email" class="required">Email</label><input type="email" id="subscribe_email" name="subscribe[email]" required="required" value="ac@gmail.com">
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div><button type="submit" id="subscribe_Suscribir" name="subscribe[Suscribir]">Suscribir</button></div>
              <input type="hidden" id="subscribe__token" name="subscribe[_token]">
            </form>


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 footer-links">
            <h4>Useful Links</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">About us</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">Services</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">Terms of service</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">Privacy policy</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 footer-links">
            <h4>Our Services</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">Web Design</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">Web Development</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">Product Management</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">Marketing</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">Graphic Design</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 footer-contact">
            <h4>Contact Us</h4>
            <p> A Street <br> New York, NY 535000<br> United States <br><br> <strong>Phone:</strong> +1 55<br> <strong>Email:</strong> info@example.com<br> </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 footer-info">
            <h3>About Me</h3>
            <p>Cras fermentum odio eu feugiat lide par naso tierra. Justo eget nada terra videa magna derita valies darta donna mare fermentum iaculis eu non diam phasellus.</p>
            <div class="social-links mt-3"> <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="bx bxl-twitter"></i></a> <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="bx bxl-facebook"></i></a> <a href="#" class="instagram"><i class="bx bxl-instagram"></i></a> <a href="#" class="linkedin"><i class="bx bxl-linkedin"></i></a>              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="copyright"> © Copyright <strong><span>Me</span></strong>. All Rights Reserved </div>
      <div class="credits"> Designed by <a href="#">Me</a> </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```